# What is Best practices for Django model ForeignKey unique=True not to be displayed in form?

Tags: django

Is there a best practice for ForeignKey unique=True values not to be displayed in the forms selection choice?

```
WarehouseBin = models.ForeignKey(WarehouseBin, unique=True)
```

It is annoying for the users to select options that they are not allowed in model.
Do I have to redefine in the view form values after it was initiated .

```
 form = ***Form(instance=post)
    form.fields['WarehouseBin'].queryset =***.objects.exclude(***)
```

Is there any other way?

Comment: Is it a ModelForm? you can exclude this filed then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice to control the content of the foreign key fields is to override your form `__init__()` method. That way your form logic is nicely separated from your view, and you can reuse the same form in your view and admin if you want to.

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from myapp.models import Article

# Create the form class.
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['pub_date', 'headline', 'content', 'reporter']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ArticleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # fetch only active reporters
        self.fields['reporter'].queryset = Repoter.objects.filter(active=True)
```

For more details see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships

BTW, since you are interested in best practices, here's another tip. You shouldn't use camel case for your class fields, but lowercase with words separated with underscore:

```
warehouse_bin = models.ForeignKey(WarehouseBin, unique=True)
```

See [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id36) for more details.

Comment: I dont think you understood correctly.
When I define my field in model as unique  "unique=True" user will be not allowed to select same value of the field more then one time . But in the Form dropdown still all the values will be displayed and user will get the message only after he will make selection. For this reason each time after form gets initiated in view file have to rewrite the form field to limit data displayed. Is there another way?